# nginx [emerg] unknown “0” variable

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I've been trying for two days to convert an .htaccess to nginx rewrite the original file looked like this:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase //

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# List of files in subdirectories will not be displayed in the browser
Options -Indexes

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .htm .html .txt
AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" .htm .html .txt
AddType "text/css; charset=UTF-8" .css
AddType "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" .js

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I have managed to comeup with this:

```
# nginx configuration 
charset utf-8; 
autoindex off; 

location /application {
rewrite ^/(?:application|modules|system)\b.* /index.php/$0 break;
} 
location /modules {
rewrite ^/(?:application|modules|system)\b.* /index.php/$0 break;
}
location /system { 
rewrite ^/(?:application|modules|system)\b.* /index.php/$0 break; 
} 
location / { 
if (!-e $request_filename){ 
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$0; 
} 
} 
location ~ \.* { 
deny all; 
}
```

But when I restart nginx I get: [emerg] unknown "0" variable
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

I do not understand why this is. Can someone pleas help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the `$0`'s with either `$uri` or `$request_uri`

Comment: You might want to clarify a bit by adding some additional information why the OP was wrong and/or providing a/the correct code sample. So your answer looks more like an answer and becomes more usable to solve similar problems of other users.

Comment: That wasn't it. This solution is overly complex for no reason other than trying to fit one application's way of doing things into a totally different application.